# how to use recursive query in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a question related to tree like structure that I try to shown you in table

```
id       name           reportsto
2        Akas           345
3        grity          345
4        kethy          2
5        alex           345
6        holy           3
7        dean           4
8        ambrose        3
9        amily          456
```

Now `reportsto` contains parent id like when I am login with `reportsto` id 345 then the contacts that reports to 345 shown and also contacts that reported to other id that id reported to 345 just like parent child relationship. So I want a result like
2,3,4,5,6,7,8 but not id 9. How to achieve that with mysql?

I have a table that contains a lot of data and its like tree structure.

Comment: MySQL doesn't support recursive queries. You need to do that in your application.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513418/how-to-do-the-recursive-select-query-in-mysql might help.